# Websphere Cluster - Spring file Listenner

Tags: java, spring, websphere-7

I have a Websphere Cluster Setup v7. Server A1 Load Balancer, A2 (deployment Manager), B(WAS) , C(WAS). In server B and C ejb,web and a spring application is deployed. Spring application listens to a folder and when a file comes to that folder it processes it and then calls the web application via web services. So when spring application is deployed in B and C. Files are processed twice resulting in duplicate records how to tackle the above problem. Should i write a java logic or any setting in websphere will do things right ?? If i have to write a java logic pls give some suggestion (reliable and easily to implement NOTE: Cluster node can increase after some times).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have application logic using Spring, and the application logic misbehaves when it is run multiple times on the same filesystem.  Is that correct?  If so, there's nothing WebSphere Application Server can do.  I suggest storing the state (whether the file has been processed) in shared storage, such as a database.

Comment: I was thinking about the shared storage implementation, but i thought give it a try with Websphere.. Thanks for ur suggestion